# gtag.js event tracking - position of the tracking code snippets

Tags: google-analytics

The question I have is almost too trivial to be posted but as I am not familiar with the deepth of the matter and i couldn't find anything helpful in the google developer pages/search function I hope to find help here.

I forwarded the task to change the "old" ga tag format to the gtag.js format to a technical partner. The general change was conducted without a problem. Unfortunately the event/conversion tracking snippets on the checkout page weren't updated properly and since weeks he can't fix it.

My question is: where does the (analytics) e-commerce event/conversion tracking code (at the checkout page) has to be placed (after the general gtag.js code in head, or in body together with/before/after the event tracking code for Google Ads)?

So either

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxxxx">       
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());

        gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
        gtag('config', 'AW-xxxxxxxxx');
        gtag('event', 'conversion', {
    'value': 77.470071,
    'currency': "EUR",
    'transaction_id': "9975"
});

</script>
```

And in body:

```
<script>

gtag('event', 'conversion', {
    'send_to': 'AW-xxxxxxxx',
    'value': 77.470071,
    'currency': "EUR",
    'transaction_id': "9975"
});
```

Or another form of the "send to" order for the analytics part with a different arrangement in the body section.

I hope to find help here. Thank you in advance!

Kind regards
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to call gtag.js before you can utilize the functions in gtag. In the  of your HTML document you always place this piece of code:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX');
      gtag('config', 'AW-XXXXXXXXX', {'send_page_view': false});
</script>
```

After the initiation, you can send data to GA and in your case Ads. In most cases, the ecommerce data is already available before the page loads. So you should be able to send this information in the :

```
<script>
gtag('event', 'purchase', {
  "send_to": "AW-XXXXXXXX/<Conversion Label>",
  "transaction_id": "24.031608523954162",
  "affiliation": "Google online store",
  "value": 23.07,
  "currency": "USD",
  "tax": 1.24,
  "shipping": 0,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "P12345",
      "name": "Android Warhol T-Shirt",
      "list_name": "Search Results",
      "brand": "Google",
      "category": "Apparel/T-Shirts",
      "variant": "Black",
      "list_position": 1,
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": '2.0'
    },
    {
      "id": "P67890",
      "name": "Flame challenge TShirt",
      "list_name": "Search Results",
      "brand": "MyBrand",
      "category": "Apparel/T-Shirts",
      "variant": "Red",
      "list_position": 2,
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": '3.0'
    }
  ]
});
</script>
```

Source:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce#2_track_checkout_options
https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/

My recommendation is to use Google Tag Manager to enable your Digital Marketing tools instead of in the code. You will get more freedom in the tools you use, but of course, some code changes are still required.

Hopefully, this clarifies stuff.

Cheers,
Raoul

Comment: Dear Raoul,
thanks for your answer. The global site tag in the head section is inserted like in your example and works. The AW-conversion tag in the body also works. My problem is that i don't know where to put the command that conversion info is sent to GA. Do i put it in the head together with/after the general gtag.js or do i put it in the body together/after the <script>
gtag('event', 'purchase', {
  "send_to": "AW-XXXXXXXX/<Conversion Label>",?

Right now conversion values do get transferred to Ads but not to Analytics. I have seen  the source but I doesnt clarify my case.

Comment: Hi Christian, After initiation, you implement the event. So both code examples can be included into the <head> after each other.

Comment: Dear Raoul, thanks a lot for the information - this is what I really need. If I may ask for one more detail my problem is solved.

If I understand it correct the structure would be:
<script>
     general gtag tag with config UA- & AW-
</script>

<script>
     gtag('event', 'conversion', {
  "send_to": "AW-XXXXXXXX/<Conversion Label>",
   ...
</script>

and at last:

<script>
gtag('event', 'conversion', {
  "send_to": "UA-xxx",
   ...
</script>

Does the tag for UA-xxx looks identical to the AW - e.g. must contain a "send_to" command?
Thanks a lot for your help!
Christian

Comment: Hi Christian, First, the initiation script for GA and Ads second the script section with the purchase event. It isn't necessary to add the conversion script second because you add "send_to": "AW-XXXXXXXX/<Conversion Label>" to the purchase event. Cheers, Raoul